# Adjust VBA code to remove subscript out range error

Tags: excel, vba, subscript

Trying to remove this error from my spreadsheets where I have similar code multiple times.
I am a novice for VBA and this keeps failing every few months with the subscript out of range error.

```
Sub DailyConvert()
        Application.EnableEvents = False
With Workbooks("Dash")
        Sheets("Dashboard").Range("DQ4:DQ250").Clear
        Sheets("Movers).Range("C5:C250").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("DQ4")
End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

I know I need to declare variables and have tried a few attempts but it keeps failing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: put a `.` in front of both lines starting with `Sheets` so it is referring to the workbook "Dash" and also the `Destination` line with `Sheets` like: `.Sheets("Dashboard").Range("DQ4:DQ250").Clear`

Comment: You have no variables so you don't need to declare any.

Comment: `With Workbooks("Dash")` would be more robust if you include the file extension in the name.

Comment: `Sheets("Movers")` Closing quotation mark is missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DailyConvert()
        Application.EnableEvents = False
With Workbooks("Dash")
        .Sheets("Dashboard").Range("DQ4:DQ250").Clear
        .Sheets("Movers").Range("C5:C250").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Dashboard").Range("DQ4")
End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Adding the period to the start of the sheets seems to have fixed it. Thank you Warcupine! And I guess I meant ranges, not variables. Taller thank you, just a typing error. And Tim I will add the full file extension as well if that will help.

Thank you all.